# Creating a list of $xy$ pairs

Tags: random

How do I create a list of $xy$ pairs of points where the $x$ points are evenly spaced between a given range with a specific step size, and the $y$ points are given by a function, but with some random noise added from a normal distribution with mean $= 0$ and standard deviation $= 1$ if I am given the function?

Answer (score 3):

A standard way would probably be

```
Table[{x, f[x] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]}, {x, x0, x1, dx}]
```

for `x` in steps of `dx` in the range `x0` to `x1`, inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = Range[1, 20, .3];

y = #^2 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]] & /@ x;

Transpose[{x, y}]
```